# Microsoft visual studio Professional 2010 on my Windows XP SP1 edition. I am getting the error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to install Microsoft visual studio Professional 2010 on my Windows XP SP1 edition. I am getting the error

Some componetnts must be installed in c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\directory. Check that you have write permission and enough space in the directory.

Note: I do  have enough space and i am Admin user too......... one more thing is that is on ISO file and i extracted using Quick mount.

Answer (score 1):

You need Windows XP - Service Pack 3. Service pack 1 is not supported.

See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/professional/system-requirements).

```
Visual Studio 2010 can be installed on the following operating systems:

Windows XP (x86) with Service Pack 3 - all editions except Starter Edition
Windows Vista (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2 - all editions except Starter Edition
Windows 7 (x86 & x64)
Windows Server 2003 (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2
Windows Server 2003 R2 (x86 & x64)
Windows Server 2008 (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2
Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64)
Supported Architectures:

32-Bit (x86)
64-Bit (x64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click the setup file and Select run as administrator